# Member function to turn class into dict

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x

I'm working on a project where I often want to turn class instances into dictionaries to write them to MongoDB. I'd like some feedback on the following:

```
def getDict(self):
    self.dict = dict()
    for key in self.__dict__.keys():
        if key not in self.NOT_INCLUDE: # class variable
            try:
                self.dict[key] = getattr(getattr(self, key), "getDict")()
            except:
                self.dict[key] = getattr(self, key)
    return self.dict
```

This will turn any class with `getDict` into a dictionary, including any instance properties that themselves have a `getDict` method.

Also please let me know if there's an easy way to do this with the standard library that I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are you Returning**

This function is adding a new member variable, `self.dict`. Presumably you want to just return a new temporary variable. Also, `dict()` is actually less efficient than `{}`, so you might want to start with:

```
member_dict = {} # or however you want to name it
```

**Iterating over a Dict**

In python, iterating over a dict is the same as iterating over the keys, so we can just save that step:

```
for key in self.__dict__:
```

But really, you don't just want the keys, you want the values too, so let's just get both:

```
for key, val in self.__dict__.items():
```

**getattr**

Use `getattr()` only for variable attribute names. Otherwise, just reference the attribute directly. `getattr(x, 'getDict')()` is more verbose and harder to parse than `x.getDict()`.

**Catching Exceptions**

Don't just catch every exception - catch the one you expect to see. In this case, `AttributeError`:

```
member_dict = {}
for key, val in self.__dict__.items():
    if key not in self.NOT_INCLUDE:
        try:
            member_dict[key] = val.getDict()
        except AttributeError:
            member_dict[key] = val
return member_dict
```

**Add a Free Function**

```
def getDictIfExists(obj):
     try:
         return obj.getDict()
     except AttributeError:
         return obj
```

This lets you write the whole thing as a generator expression

```
return {key: getDictIfExists(val)
        for key, val in self.__dict__.items()
        if key not in self.NOT_INCLUDE}
```

Comment: wow I love this. I want a full dictionary, not a generator, but otherwise these comments will definitely be adopted.

Comment: @sunny The generator expression will give you a full dictionary.

Comment: @sunny Generators only return as generator objects when they're in parentheses: `()`. When wrapped in `{}` or `[]` they're returning collection objects like dictionaries and lists.

Comment: @Barry Looks like it's an AttributeError rather than a NameError that should be caught.

Comment: @sunny My bad, picked the wrong one!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't even seem that necessary to have `self.dict`. And if you are going to keep it, `dict` is not a good attribute name. `values` would be better, but it's best if you can indicate what the actual use of the dictionary is.

Likewise `getDict` isn't great, `get_values` would be better. And `NOT_INCLUDE` is less direct and clear than `EXCLUDE`. You ought to add a docstring too, that at least references the values that are excluded.

```
def get_values(self):
    """Return dictionary of objects attributes, excluding some values.

    The excluded values are found in the EXCLUDE constant."""
```

Comment: `get_values` is not good either. It should be `as_dict`.